# is groupId required for plugins in Maven pom.xml?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin

In my pom.xml if I give the following, it seems to work.

```
      <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
      </plugin>
```

is groupId not required for plugins?
If groupId is not given, how does maven download the plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the pom.xml you can define a plugin via groupId, artifactId and version. But for the groupId there is defined a default value in the [Maven 4.0.0 XSD file](https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd). If you take a look at the definition for plugins (here an excerpt from the XSD file):

```
<xs:complexType name="Plugin">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation source="version">4.0.0+</xs:documentation>
<xs:documentation source="description"> The <code>&lt;plugin&gt;</code> element contains informations required for a plugin. </xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:all>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="groupId" type="xs:string" default="org.apache.maven.plugins">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation source="version">4.0.0+</xs:documentation>
<xs:documentation source="description">The group ID of the plugin in the repository.</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="artifactId" type="xs:string">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation source="version">4.0.0+</xs:documentation>
<xs:documentation source="description">The artifact ID of the plugin in the repository.</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="version" type="xs:string">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation source="version">4.0.0+</xs:documentation>
<xs:documentation source="description">The version (or valid range of versions) of the plugin to be used.</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="extensions" type="xs:string
```

There you can see that for the groupId a default value `org.apache.maven.pugins` is defined. That means every time you do not define a groupId in the areas `plugin` and `ReportPlugin` it will automatically using the groupId. `org.apache.maven.plugins` for this.

The [mentioned search for plugins is something different](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html#configuring-maven-to-search-for-plugins). This is the case for calling a plugin goal from command linke like the following:

```
mvn versions:set ...
mvn help:help ...
```

by default the given names will be search in two groupId's: `org.apache.maven.plugins` and `org.codehaus.mojo`. The name of the plugin itself is searched based on two naming patterns `maven-${prefix}-plugin` which is the case for all Maven plugins which are developed in the Apache Software Foundation ([including the trade mark of the ASF](https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html#Plugin_Naming_Convention_and_Apache_Maven_Trademark) related to that namespace which also includes the groupId) and the second naming pattern `${prefix}-maven-plugin`.

Comment: It is not documented anywhere that `groupId` has a default value, is it? Neither the [POM Reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins) nor the [Guide to Configuring Plug-ins](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html) seem to mention this.

Comment: Please check the [XSD file](https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd) there are the defaults defined.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the default value is specified in the XSD file, but my point is that this is most likely not where users will look for this. Instead they will look in the Maven guides (see comment above); I have created [MNGSITE-453](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNGSITE-453) for this now, requesting it to be documented in the guides as well.